# What are the general steps for creating a multi view application with Xcode 4.3.2?

Tags: ios

I am using a slightly outdated book to learn iOS dev. I can't find equivalent file types on Xcode 4.3.2 to create a Windows-based multi-view application. What file types should I be using on 4.3.2? Thank you!

Comment: In particular, is there an equivalent to the UITableViewController subclass template in Xcode 4.3.2?

Comment: Did you got to File>New File... Select Objective-C Class in the left hand side, select UIViewController subclass.... in pop up name your class, and select 'UITableViewController' in the 'subclass of' drop down?